# How to prevent Entity Framework Core from issuing SQL queries against MigrationHistory and EdmMetadata

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Entity Framework Core is sending this SQL query to the SQL Server:

```
SELECT
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
go

SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[ModelHash] AS [ModelHash]
FROM [dbo].[EdmMetadata] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC
go
```

https://www.tallan.com/blog/2019/05/02/taking-a-look-at-entity-framework-queries-pt-1-net-framework

How can we stop sending these queries?

---

**Application Codes:**
This is in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConnectionString")));
```

And this is DbContext:

```
 public class AppContext: DbContext
    {
        public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Currency> Currency { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set; }
    }
```

**Problem Statement:**
We are not using migration and all tables are already exist. As a result, when Entity Framework Core generates these queries, SQL Server Profiler logs errors because __MigrationHistor and EdmMetadata do not exist.

Comment: Please don't post one and the same question. EF Core **does not** automatically issue SQL queries against migration history table, and there is no `EdmMetadata` at all. What you are showing are SQLs from EF6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IvanStoev said "EF Core does not automatically issue SQL queries against migration history table"

Those queries were generated by a library that uses Entity Framework 6.